# Java String Literal

Tags: java, string

```
String s1 = "ABC";
s1.replace("ABC","abc");
print(s1); // prints ABC as output
s1 = s1.replace("ABC","abc");
print(s1); //prints abc
```

What's the difference between two replace statements?

What happens internally when the first replace statement is called?

Comment: The second replace is the same as the first, except you are discard the result in the first one.

Comment: Since when does `replace()` have only one parameter?

Answer (score 5):

[String.replace(CharSequence first, CharSequence second)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) returns a new String reference and this is why the output is different.

In the first *replace* line you're not assigning the resulting String to anything, whereas in the second you're replacing the reference of `s1` with the result of the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

`s1.replace("ABC","abc");` doesn't replace on `s1`. It gives output of the replaced string.

```
$s2 = s1.replace("ABC","abc");;


print($s1); // prints ABC

print ($s2); // prints abc
```

Comment: Since when does `replace()` have only one parameter?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `s1.replace("ABC", "abc")` imagine that in that place new string abc is created and not assigned to anything. But with `s1=s1.replace("ABC", "abc")` you create new string abc and assign it to the s1 variable replacing old value.

Comment: Since when does `replace()` have only one parameter?

Comment: @Bohemian: THAT is the real question!!

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. It means changes are not made directly into them instead a copy of the string is created and it is changed and the reference of the changed one is returned. If you do not accept the new reference you will find the old string unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Read the API and the Java tutorials... String can NEVER be changed. That means all its methods will return a new object and your reference will still point to the old one. To assign the return to your reference, you have to assign it as in

```
s1 = s1.replace("ABC","abc");
```

Be careful with that! Quite tricky ;)

If you will change the String a lot, use [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead... There your appends, replaces, etc have effect in the object referenced by your variable.

Comment: The javadoc for StringBuffer tells you to use StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace()` Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Code of **[String.replace](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28char,char%29)**